# Heap Corruption when Invoking Destructor on array of objects using delete []

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I am new to programming and currently trying to learn data structures. I am currently trying to implement an array of queues of type array, however when deallocating memory using the `delete [] queues` statement, the program runs into a Heap corruption error. The issue seem to deal with the inner for loop + while loop, but I'm a bit confused. I have looked at other existing questions, which point me to a memory allocation problem. However, when I fill the queue array up to size N/2 I still run into the Heap corruption error. What is triggering this issue?

```
void queue_client(){

int M = 2;
int N = 10;

//create an array of queues
Queue_array<int>* queues = new Queue_array<int>[M];

//initialize each queue in the array of queues
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    queues[i].set_array(N);
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){

    //randonly pick number to select and put in queue
    int in = rand() % M, out = rand() % M;

    queues[in].put(i);

    std::cout << i << " in" <<std::endl;

    //if current queues is not empty pop element out
    if (!queues[out].empty()) {
        std::cout << queues[out].get() << " out" << std::endl;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
        //Queue_array<int> q = queues[k];
        std::cout << k << ": ";

        while (!queues[k].empty()) {
            std::cout << queues[k].get() << " ";
        }
    }
}

//deallocate memory from array queue
delete[] queues;

}
```

Attached is the queue array class. The issue seems to be with my queue_array class, possibly the destructor?

```
#include<iostream>
template <class Item>
class Queue_array
{
private:
    Item* q;
    int N, head, tail;

    void deleteList() {
            delete [] q;
            std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    Queue_array(int maxN);
    Queue_array();
    ~Queue_array();
    Queue_array& operator=(Queue_array& rhs);
    int empty();
    void put(Item item);
    Item get();
    void print_elements();
    int error(int);
    bool search_element(Item);
    int get_size();
    void set_array(int);
};

template <class Item>
Queue_array<Item>::Queue_array(int maxN) {
    q = new Item[maxN+1];
    N = maxN+1;
    head = N;
    tail = 0;
}
template <class Item>
Queue_array<Item>::Queue_array() {
    q = 0;
    N = 0;
    head = N;
    tail = 0;
}
template <class Item>
Queue_array<Item>::~Queue_array() {
    std::cout << "destructor invoked" << std::endl;
    deleteList();
}
template <class Item>
Queue_array<Item>& Queue_array<Item>::operator=(Queue_array& rhs) {

    //if both are the same queues return the queue
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    }

    //clear all elements in current queue
    deleteList();
    
    this->set_array(rhs.get_size());

    //pop all elements from rhs and put into current queue 
    while (!rhs.empty()) {
        put(rhs.get());
    }

    return *this;
}

template<class Item>
void Queue_array<Item>::set_array(int val) {
    N = val+1;
    q = new Item[val+1];
    head = N;
    tail = 0;
}
template <class Item>
int Queue_array<Item>::empty() {
    return (head % N == tail);
}

template<class Item>
void Queue_array<Item>::put(Item item) {

    if (!error(2))
    {
    q[tail++] = item;
    tail = tail % N;
    }
}

template<class Item>
Item Queue_array<Item>::get() {

    if (!error(1))
    {
    head = head % N;
    return q[head++];
    }
}

template<class Item>
void Queue_array<Item>::print_elements() {

    std::cout <<"-----------------------" <<std::endl;
    if (tail > head) {
        //std::cout << "Head < Tail ";
        for (int i = head; i < tail; i++) {
            std::cout  << q[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        //std::cout << "Tail < Head ";
        int i;
        
        //if tail is less than head, that means array indexes has wrapped around.

        //break print loops into two halves, from head to N and 0 to tails
        for (i = head; i < N; i++) {
            std::cout  << q[i] << " ";
        }
        
        for (i = 0; i < tail; i++) {
            std::cout << q[i] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-----------------------" <<std::endl;
}

template<class Item>
int Queue_array<Item>::error(int mode) {
    
    //if all elements are popped and head = tail
    if (empty() && (mode==1)) {

        //if first element is detected return 0
        if (head == N) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error, queue is empty." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //if tail wraps back to head (tail leads head, queue is full)
    else if ((((tail%N) +1) == head) && (mode ==2)) {
        //if tail is at last node, don't insert node
        std::cout << "Error, queue is full." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
template<class Item>
bool Queue_array<Item>::search_element(Item x) {

    int start = head;

    if (start == N)
        start = 0;

    for (int i = start; i <= tail; i++) {
        if (q[i] == x) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
template<class Item>
int Queue_array<Item>::get_size() {
    return N;
}
```

I made tested the queue array and the destructor is being invoked correctly. The test client simply puts N int values in each of the M Queues.

```
void test_4_71() {
    //test if destructor is working.

    int M = 2;
    int N = 10;

    //create an array of queues
    Queue_array<int>* queues = new Queue_array<int>[M];

    //initialize each queue in the array of queues
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        queues[i].set_array(N);
    }

    //push 0,1,2,...10 to arrays 1 and 2
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            queues[i].put(j);

        std::cout << i << " in" << std::endl;
    }

    //pop all elements from arrays 1 and 2
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {

        while (!queues[i].empty()) {
            std::cout << queues[i].get() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //deallocate memory from array queue
    delete[]queues;

    //std::cout << queues[0].get() << "test get" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You allocate 2 `Queue_array`s but then use 10 of them. 8 too many.

Comment: Where is the `Queue_array` copy constructor?  That class violates the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  This simple code reveals the bug: `int main() { Queue_array q1(10); Queue_array q2 = q1; }`  -- double `detete[]` error.

Answer (score 0):

The heap corruption problem was solved after fixing this portion of the code:

```
//initialize each queue in the array of queues
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    queues[i].set_array(N);
}
```

I have also added a copy constructor to follow the rule of 3 for Abstract ADT's.

Copy constructor:

```
template <class Item>

Queue_array<Item>::Queue_array(const Queue_array& rhs) {
    q = new Item[rhs.N];

    N = rhs.N;
    head = rhs.head;
    tail = rhs.tail;

    //copy all elements from rhs to this queue array
    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.tail; i++) {
        q[i] = rhs.q[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you added the copy constructor, then the assignment operator you wrote can be changed to simply the following: `Queue_array& operator=(const Queue_array& rhs) { if (&rhs != this) { Queue_array temp(rhs); std::swap(temp.N, N); std::swap(temp.head, head); std::swap(temp.tail, tail), std::swap(temp.q, q); } return *this; }`,  See the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)